# bash: ensure one line at a time from stdout written to file when backgrounding multiple processes

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have the following script:

```
loop=0
for did in $(echo "$dids")
do
    echo "$did"
    loop=$((loop+1))
    if [ $loop -lt 10 ] ; then
        ./account_locate_by_phonenumber.sh "$did" 2>/dev/null >>accounts.csv &
    else
        wait
        #make sure to call locate script again or we'll skip this phone number
        ./account_locate_by_phonenumber.sh "$did" 2>/dev/null >>accounts.csv &
        loop=0
    fi
done
```

It's calling another script
    account_locate_by_phonenumber.sh
which gets results from a remote mysql server via ssh.

If I don't background the calls to that script I have no problem.  The problem comes when backgrounding the calls.  I currently do ten iterations then call wait in order to briefly pause and not completely overwhelm the remote server.  Most lines written are fine, but every so often (between 10-50 lines) two lines are written at once, and the output is all mixed up.

I assume I need to somehow capture the input and then write it all at once, or per set of iterations, but I'm blanking on how this could be done.

Comment: `$(echo "dids")` is more idiomatically and succinctly written `"dids"`. See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo

Comment: @tripleee: I think you meant to write, "`$(echo "$dids")` is more idiomatically and succinctly written `$dids`."

Comment: Right you are, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write each iteration's output to a different file and concatenate them.

```
loop=0
for did in $(echo "$dids")
do
    echo "$did"
    loop=$((loop+1))
    if [ $loop -lt 10 ] ; then
        ./account_locate_by_phonenumber.sh "$did" 2>/dev/null >accounts.csv.$loop &
    else
        wait
        cat accounts.csv.* >> accounts.csv
        rm accounts.csv.*
        #make sure to call locate script again or we'll skip this phone number
        ./account_locate_by_phonenumber.sh "$did" 2>/dev/null >accounts.csv.0 &
        loop=0
    fi
done
wait
cat accounts.csv.* >> accounts.csv
```

Comment: this works beautifully.  I wanted to avoid lots of disk i/o for fear of slowing stuff down.  Clearly there's little to no slow down on this fast server.

Comment: If that does become a problem, you could put the intermediate files in `/tmp`. This is often configured as a RAM disk, so there no disk I/O unless VM fills up and it has to page it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're tied to using Bash here... how about:

- You write your output to 10 separate numbered csv files
- Replace the time interval wait with a wait for all csv files to populated
- Add a combine script after the 10th iteration to push all csv files into your main accounts.csv

Otherwise, I would suggest using a language that has more library support for multiple threads.